# How do you configure Sphinx to ignore parentheses in search results?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

So that the search "Example" returns "(Example)"

I tried to place the bracket UTF code in ignore_chars but this doesn't work.

Current config is below:

```
production:
  version: 1.10-beta
  wordforms: lib/wordforms.txt
  stopwords: lib/stopwords.txt 
  charset_table: "0..9, a..z, _, U+023, A..Z->a..z, U+410..U+42F->U+430..U+44F, U+430..U+44F"
  ignore_chars: "U+0027, U+0028"
  morphology: stem_en
```

Answer (score 0):

All chars not listed in charset_table are counted as seperators anyway. So as you dont have them in your charset table, they wont ever be indexed as part of words.

So it will work anyway. You must have something else wrong.

NB, round brackets are hex 28 and 29. 27 is a single quote.